# Proper way to create a syntax file in vim that depends on another syntax file

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I am currently creating a Vim syntax file for WordPress and have it inside a file called `wordpress.vim`

All WordPress files are PHP files but not all PHP files are WordPress files.

My `wordpress.vim` syntax file depends on the php syntax file. So I have included it using the following line

```
so <sfile>:p:h/php.vim
```

My question is what is the most elegant way to include all PHP syntax into WordPress syntax and where should I put the the new `wordpress.vim` file that I have created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right location for your syntax file should be:

```
~/.vim/syntax/wordpress.vim
```

You should take a look at `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/cpp.vim` for what I assume is the correct syntax:

```
if version < 600
  syntax clear
elseif exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif

" Read the C syntax to start with
if version < 600
  so <sfile>:p:h/c.vim
else
  runtime! syntax/c.vim
  unlet b:current_syntax
endif
```

Comment: .. and I should manually set the syntax for WordPress file right?

Comment: Since they are `*.php`, yes. You can use an ftplugin for that and `:set ft=wordpress`. You can use `:h modeline` if it's getting boring.

Comment: cpp.vim is kinda bad example, because of its age, it carries a lot of baggage with it. Since nobody's using Vim 5.x any more, you can drop the conditionals, and just use the `else` parts.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Ingo. I took the first that came to mind, though.